# Why can't we use the same logical operator (AND/OR) for the same situation (input "Q"/"q") in "if" and "while"?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() { 
 char selection {};
 do {

        cout<<"\n---------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"1  do this "<<endl;
        cout<<"2  do that "<<endl;
        cout<<"3  do something else  "<<endl;
        cout<<"q  Quit  "<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter your selection : ";
        cin>>selection;

        if (selection=='1')
            cout<<"You chose 1 -- doing this "<<endl;
        else if (selection=='2')
            cout<<"You chose 2-- doing that "<<endl;
        else if (selection=='3')
            cout<<"You chose 3-- doing something else  "<<endl;
        else if (selection=='Q'||selection=='q')
            cout<<"Goodbye! "<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"Unknown value --try again  "<<endl;
 } while (selection!='q'&& selection!='Q');
 cout<<endl;   

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use logical AND and logical OR. Please describe what problem you are having. This code looks fine to me.

Comment: Google for the laws of DeMorgan in boolean logic.

Comment: !A && !B == !(A || B)

Comment: @Swordfish The strange thing is that OP appears to understand DeMorgan's laws so I don't understand what the question is about.

Comment: @john I'm not sure if he understands.

Comment: @Swordfish You might be right. But the code is OK. It's easier to understand what the OP doesn't understand if they post incorrect code than if they post correct code.

Comment: Please post some code that you think should work but doesn't. That will make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: @john as I understand the question he struggles to formulate both conditions with a logic or or with a logic and.

Comment: Hello sir , Thank you for answering my question ! I know the code is right i just want to ask  you that why can't we use logical And in  if else q condition and  logical Or in while condition

Comment: Still not sure what you mean. Please edit the question and specify exactly the code you think should or should not be accepted (e.g. *Why do we use `selection!='q'&& selection!='Q'` and not `!(selection=='q' || selection=='Q')` for the `while` condition*).

Answer (score 6):

You are wondering why the two conditions, while semantically describing the same end situation use opposite operators (AND vs. OR).

```
if (selection=='Q'||selection=='q')
/* ... */
while (selection!='q'&& selection!='Q')
```

They *can* use the same operator, if you correctly invert it.

I.e.

```
if    ( (selection=='Q' || selection=='q'))
/* ... */
while (!(selection=='q' || selection=='Q'))
```

or

```
if    (!(selection!='Q'&& selection!='q'))
/* ... */
while ( (selection!='q'&& selection!='Q'))
```

(I was a little generous with the `()` to be more suggestive, obviously a few of them are not needed.)

Because the first one is an inversion of the second one.
You want to do something "if" and you want to loop "while not".

Just as a lateral solution, as long as you do not have a `break` anywhere in the loop, you can move the "Goodbye" out of the loop and unconditionally execute it afterwards. Then you check the end condition only once, instead of twice. In my opinion this improves readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 2):

> **Why can't we use the same logical operator (AND/OR) for the same situation (input “Q”/“q”) in “if” and “while”?**

Because it is not the same situation. Why? Let's see:

```
else if (selection=='Q'||selection=='q')
```

Above code says, **If this condition is true**, that is if `selection` is q or Q, then exit.

```
while (selection!='q'&& selection!='Q')
```

And this one says, **if the condition is not true**, keep looping.

---

You can still use `||` or `&&` in both conditions if you want. For example, both of the following are equivalent:

```
while (selection!='q'&& selection!='Q')
//
while( !(selection == 'q' || selection == 'Q') )
```

See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63150087/2279422) by Yunnosch for more details on this.

Comment: Would you like to make the additional insight more obvious which your answer provides in comparison to the noticably older existing answer? (admittedly mine)

Comment: The only point of my answer was to highlight that the situation is not the same. Your answer says this as well, but not as evidently. It, however, goes into depth about how to use the same operators. If you can highlight this in your answer in the beginning, I will take mine down

Comment: No need to take yours down. With your explanation I now believe that you try to provide a different angle, that is all I wanted to verify. The fact that I did not see it by myself does not invalidate that. Keep it.

Comment: I made my answer on the idea that the "situation", the "point of time", the "semantic condition" is the same. You point out that the logical condition (in the scope of my answer I'd call that the "syntactical situation", to make a contrast) is different. That is a nice different angle. Both together, or their contrast, seem enlightening and helpful. I start to like your answer. ;-)

Comment: Nice style, standing up to a challenge, defending your point and staying polite and matter-of-fact at the same time.