# How to ask question continuously until it meets requirements of having to meet a condition in c

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, cs50

I am using the cs50 online IDE so I am also using the cs50 library at the top. I am trying to make it keep asking the question "Are you okay?" until you either say "y" or "n" (upper or lowercase).

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 
    char answer;
    do
    {
        char answer = get_char("are you okay Y/N ");
        if (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
        {
            printf("you are okay");
        }
            else if (answer == 'n' || answer == 'N')
        {
            printf("you are not okay ");
        }

    }
   
    while(answer != 'y' || answer != 'Y' || answer != 'n' || answer != 'N');
    
}
```

Comment: Change `||` to `&&` in `while` condition.

Comment: If you learn about [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) (which I really recommend you should), then you will learn that the opposite of `answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y'` is *not* `answer != 'y' || answer != 'Y'`.

Comment: Please use punctuation and capitalisation instead of meangingless bold-formatting. The people you ask for help will perceive that as politeness and get an impression that you spent effort on asking for help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't we use the same logical operator (AND/OR) for the same situation (input "Q"/"q") in "if" and "while"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63149843/why-cant-we-use-the-same-logical-operator-and-or-for-the-same-situation-inpu)

Comment: Im sorry I don’t really use stack overflow much i am just trying to learn c in CS50 and was trying to write code to test what i have learned i just want to know what a viable solution is to this

Comment: and how would I go about learning De Morgan's laws I only know secondary school level math

Comment: NOT(A and B) == NOT(A) or NOT(B), and also: NOT(a or B) == NOT(a) and NOT(b).

Comment: By asking your search engine, which gives [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: So how would it be solved in this specific context i might understand it like that

Comment: @Fkhadim123 you've already got the exact answer on what you need to change on the first comment as well as the reason behind it with the mention of De Morgan's law.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When learning boolean logic in C, common sense will get you very far. That is: make it a habit of saying the lines you write out loud/in your head:

`while(answer != 'y' || answer != 'Y' || answer != 'n' || answer != 'N');`

translated to English:

> "while the answer is not `y` or it is not `Y` or it is not..."

Here you should smell a fish. Correct English/logic would rather be:

> "while the answer is not `y` *and* it is not `Y` *and*..."

Common sense aside, [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) is pretty much necessary prerequisite knowledge before studying any programming.

Comment: the program still dosent compile

Comment: actually its because I declared 'answer' twice it compiles now and works as expected