# scanf until number fits in condition

Tags: c

The request is that the user must input numbers until they fit within the numbers 1 and 13

```
for (N=0; N>13 && N<1; scanf("%d",&N))
{
    printf("fits");
}
```

This doesn't work, do I have to rephrase it somehow?

Comment: How does it not work? What are the undesired symptoms? Please provide a [mre] to demonstrate them.

Comment: I think this is the same problem as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69458480/how-to-compare-char-array-with-char-in-c-language/69458744 but probably not obviously enough to be considered a duplicate.

Comment: Not checking the return value from `scanf` always leads to undefined behaviour. This can be seen as a case of [de Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: Please clarify "within 1 and 13 "; including 1 and 13 as good, or exclusing them as unwanted.

Answer (score 2):

Your programmed condition `N>13 && N<1` can never be true. So your loop body and the `scanf("%d",&N)` is never executed.

You do not want to "loop while the number is bigger than 13 AND lower than 1": you probably want to "loop while the number bigger than 13 OR lower than 1".

So `N > 13 || N < 1`.

Comment: You will probably find out, that you also want to make a check on the return value of scanf(), but that is beyond the scope of your question.

Answer (score -1):

- The problem with your code is that `N > 13 && N < 1` will always be
  false.

> A number can never be greater than 13 and less than 1 at the same time

- You have to use `|| operator` for the comparison like `N > 13 || N < 1`, Also `N = 0` is redundant in your code.
- And also you have to move the print statement outside the loop, otherwise, it will print `fits` every time it is not in the range.

```c
int main()
{
    int input;
    int flag = scanf("%d", &input) == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    while (input < 1 || input > 13)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            while (getchar()!='\n');
        }
        int flag = scanf("%d", &input) == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    printf("fits");
    return 0;
}
```

`while (getchar()!='\n')` is used to clean the `stdin`.

> when a user enters a non-numeric character `scanf` returns 0, So to prevent unexpected behavior you've to clean `stdin` first before calling another `scanf` statement.

Comment: You need to check that `scanf()` does not report zero because some non-numeric character was entered.  Also, `N` is not initialized on the first iteration.